# Find/Prove Compact Subspace that is Non-Closed

Tags: general-topology, compactness

Let $\tau = \{\varnothing\} \cup \{G \subseteq \mathbb R: \mathbb R-G \ $is finite $\} $ and  $(\tau,\mathbb R)$ is the topology of the cofinite space. 
Find a compact set $K \subseteq \mathbb R $ that is not closed.

We have just started topology and I am a bit stumped.

**My ideas:** As I need to find a set $K \subseteq\mathbb R $ whereby $K^{C}$ is finite. I would naturally suggest $\mathbb R-\{0\}$ or excluding some other finite subset, but then I get trouble in proving that it is compact. Any hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take any countable subset $C$ of $\mathbb R$. Since it is neither $\mathbb R$ nor a finite set, it is not closed.

However, it is compact. Let $(A_\lambda)_{\lambda\in\Lambda}$ is an open cover of $C$. Take $c\in C$. Then there is a $\lambda_0\in\Lambda$ such that $c\in A_{\lambda_0}$. In particular, $A_{\lambda_0}\neq\emptyset$. SInce it is an open set, $\mathbb{R}\setminus A_{\lambda_0}$ is finite. So, only finitely many elements $c_1,\ldots,c_n$ of $C$ don't belong to $a_{\lambda_0}$. For each $k\in\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$, take $\lambda_k\in\Lambda$ such that $c_k\in A_{\lambda_k}$. Then $\bigl\{A_{\lambda_k}\,|\,k\in\{0,1,\ldots,n\}\bigr\}$ is a finite subcover of $(A_\lambda)_{\lambda\in\Lambda}$.

Comment: Thank you very much. One question though: What is the relevance of the definition of the topology $\tau$? I would have thought my subset $C$ would have to be $\in \tau$. But clearly a countable set $C$ is not $\in \tau$

Comment: Without the topology $\tau$, asking whether a set is closed or asking whether it is compact would make no sens. And the question was whether there is a subset **of the reals** which is compact but not closed.

Comment: I'm just missing something: why is $\mathbb R - A_{\lambda_{0}}$ finite as a result of $A_{\lambda_{0}}$ being open?

Comment: Because $A_{\lambda_0}\in\tau$ means that $A_{\lambda_0}=\emptyset$ or that $\mathbb{R}\setminus A_{\lambda_0}$ is finite. Since $A_{\lambda_0}\neq\emptyset$, $\mathbb{R}\setminus A_{\lambda_0}$ is finite

Comment: Of course, thanks!